# LCD Power sequencing

Tags: power-supply, lcd, tft

According to datasheet of LCD TFT ( https://www.gms-ds.com/fileadmin/produkte/pdf/DLC0700BIG-1.pdf ) page 11 there is power sequence necessary for proper initialization of LCD.

On the other hand at page 7 "Absolute maximum ratings" voltage (exclude AVDD) have large range from nearly zero voltage.

This means that we can avoid necessity of power suquence (f.e. if VGL will start before AVDD becouse VGL can have 0V according to absolute ratings values)?

Thanks for any answers.

Comment: the datasheet specifies VGL to be -7 V

Comment: "Absolute maximum ratings" are limits which limit the life of the component. Power sequencing is required to make it stable. Follow the datasheet fully. if the datasheet askes for power sequencing, follow it.

Answer (score 2):

When a part is used outside normal operating range, it does not have to work, even if it is below absolute maximum ratings.

Absolute maximum ratings only mean no permanent damage happens, at least not immediately.

So, it basically means you can't randomly sequence the supplies within absolute maximum ratings and assume that the display initializes and works properly.